# Preventing context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) error with HTTP 200 OK

Tags: go, tcp, server-timing

I have a client and server. Server process the request more than 2 seconds. But client does not have so much time. It needs to get response in 1 seconds. That's why it responds with

*Get "http://localhost:8888": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference*

Question?
How can I change server.go  in such a way that all errors are properly recovered
and that the endpoint is always available?
**Note** that the endpoint, the client is calling, should process request as quickly as possible and return a 200 OK as soon as it done.

client.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    c := &http.Client{Timeout: 2 * time.Second}

    res, err := c.Get("http://localhost:8888")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    var r []byte

    _, err = res.Body.Read(r)
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

server.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func slowHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    io.WriteString(w, "I am slow!\n")
}

func main() {
    srv := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8888",
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(slowHandler),
    }

    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Server failed: %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can recover from panic by implementing a recovery Middleware, something like:

```golang
 defer func() {
      if err := recover(); err != nil {
        log.Println("recovered from panic", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "recovered from panic")
      }
    }()
```

you can use this useful article as a guideline https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/middlewares-golang-best-practices-examples

EDIT

you can create a custom Middleware to handle a custom handler timeout

```golang
func timeOutMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        done := make(chan bool)
        ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), time.Second*1)
        defer cancelFunc()
        go func() {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            close(done)
        }()
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case <-ctx.Done():
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"message": "handled time out"}`))
        }
    })

}
```

in order for this to work you need to sync with the client because if the client sets a lower timeout then will never get a proper response, or in the case the server sets a very low timeout this could happen as well.

also to fully read the response bytes use this

```golang
defer res.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
```

Comment: ahh my bad, is not the server panicking is the client because you are reading a nil response due to the timeout, in your example the client never gets answer from server, thus, r is nil and the panic. two things here you can do for now: 

- client error handling `if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() { `

- server handler timeout `Handler: http.TimeoutHandler(http.HandlerFunc(slowHandler), 1*time.Second, "I timed out!\n"),` this one will return 503 but will return as soon as the timeout is completed

Comment: Lets assume the this service is public service and it takes unpredictable time and there can be many  clients. Some can assign 1 sec others more. Your code does not work in that case,

Comment: I am not sure if what you're saying is even possible, the only thing I can think about out is receiving a parameter/header in the request and then adjusting the context timeout according to that, otherwise you cannot know what's the client timeout set up.

Comment: Unfortunately , you cannot get client timeout from request header.

Comment: I meant a custom header/parameter that the client need to know before hand